# Why is this CSS rule not applied?

Tags: css

I don't have experience as a web designer, but in effort to learn more about CSS, I'm doing the stylesheet for my own page. I am aware the way I'm doing it now probably sucks, is not the recommended way, but please help me understand why this isn't working.

I have this form:

```
<form action="/register" method="POST" id="registration_form">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

I have included [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), before including my own stylesheet, and I have this rule in my CSS:

```
#registration_form label {
    width: 100px;
}
```

I also tried to put:

```
label {
   width:100px;
}
```

I tried changing the value to more than 100px, but still it doesn't get applied. If it helps, I have a layout, which contains something like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="navigation">
     ...
   </div>
   <div id="pagebox">
     {% block body %}{% endblock %}
   </div>
</body>
```

This is a jinja2 template, and the content of body is added by some different view, when it's rendered. Here are the styles for these id's:

```
#navigation {
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation ul li {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:50px;
}

#pagebox {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    height:600px;
    background-color: #20f000;
}
```

Why isn't my label style getting applied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that `<label>` has the `display:inline` by default, so `width` and `height` do not affect it. Try adding `display: inline-block` to it.

**Added:** As member [Geoff Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327744/geoff-adams) noted in the comments, there are some browser compatibility issues with `display: inline-block`. In this specific scenarion it should work, but [see here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) for more information.

Comment: `display: inline-block` isn't truly cross-browser unfortunately. If you need it to work on older browsers (read: Internet Explorer) then you may need to `display: block`, `float: left` and enter the wonderful world of the floating box model :)

Comment: @Geoff Adams - how old IE are we talking? IE6 would support this specific scenario.

Comment: well, IE6/7 support requires a CSS trick/hack to make it work, makes it slightly less simple than a one line solution. Looking at it now, even FF2 had issues with `inline-block` too.

Comment: Note: if you make an element float then you can use box properties like width anyway. If you do use float you should also set `display: inline` to [prevent IE bugs like double-margin](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html).

Comment: Sorry for very old comment, but I'd like to know if there's such tool that checks if particular property will actually work on element? Because many times I find myself wondering why some things don't work, it would be great to have such tool where you can scan your css and know if properties that you apply actually are valid.

Comment: @Erasus - Well, I don't know of such a tool _per se_, but you can always use a browser's built-in developer tools. With those you can easily see what the final CSS looks on an element and which rule comes from where and what overrides what.

Answer (score 3):

The `label` element is an inline element, so the `width` style doesn't apply to it.

You could make the `label` and `input` element float inside the `p` elements. Applying `overflow` to the `p` element makes it work as a container for the floating elements:

```
#registration_form p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#registration_form p label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
#registration_form p input {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! This is more complex than I ever imagined :)